# when i tried to run the below program null value assigning to person 1(input) without giving any name to it

Tags: c

when i tried to run this program it will automatically assigning null value to person 1(input) without giving any name as input to it . It is working normally from person 2 onwards...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int comp(const void * a, const void * b )
{
    return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}

int main ()
{
    int n;
    printf("enter no of persons: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char *arr[n+1],buf[100];
    printf("enter their names: \n");
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("person %d: ",i+1);
        arr[i]= strdup(gets(buf));
    }
    qsort (arr, n, sizeof (char*), comp);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        printf ("%s\n", arr[i]);
        free (arr[i]);
    }
}
```

output :

```
   enter no of persons: 5
   enter their names:
   person 1: person 2:sai
   person 3: santosh
   person 4: prasanth
   person 5: anil
```

Comment: because you are using `scanf()`. And, almost naturally, you're abusing it. It's extremely hard to use `scanf()` correctly. Use `fgets()` and `strtod()` instead. And ***DO NOT EVER USE `gets()`. AT ALL.*** It's insecure and non-standard. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: I see no need for `n+1` pointers in this.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n);` --> `scanf("%d%*c",&n);` : drop newline.

Comment: The quickfix would be to replace `%d` with `%d/n` so that scanf consumes the first newline

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe I guess that should be _%d\n_

Comment: Indeed ... stupid phone 'keyboard'

Comment: so, what exactly scanf("%d%*c",&n); will do?

Answer (score 0):

scanf follows the format specifierd when you write a number followed by pressing carriage return the carriage return the buffer contains the number and the new line character. When you write scanf("%d", &n); the NL is still in the buffer.

instead do like this to read input from keyboard:

```
if ( fgets( buf, sizeof( buf ), stdin ) != NULL )
{
  if (sscanf( buf, "%d", &n ) == 1)
  {
  ...
  }
}
```